# Creating (boxed) primitive instance when the class is known

Tags: java, class, types, primitive, boxing

I need a method that returns an instance of the supplied class type. Let's assume that the supplied types are limited to such that an "empty" instance of them can be created. For instance, supplying `String.class` would return an empty String, supplying an `Integer.class` would return an Integer whose initial value is zero, and so on. But how do I create (boxed) primitive types on the fly? Like this?

```
public Object newInstance(Class<?> type) {
    if (!type.isPrimitive()) {
        return type.newInstance(); // plus appropriate exception handling
    } else {
        // Now what?
        if (type.equals(Integer.class) || type.equals(int.class)) {
            return new Integer(0);
        }
        if (type.equals(Long.class) // etc.... 
    }
}
```

Is the only solution to iterate through all the possible primitive types, or is there a more straightforward solution? Note that both

```
int.class.newInstance()
```

and

```
Integer.class.newInstance()
```

throw an `InstantiationException` (because they don't have nullary constructors).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suspect the simplest way is to have a map:

```
private final static Map<Class<?>, Object> defaultValues = 
    new HashMap<Class<?>, Object>();
static
{
    defaultValues.put(String.class, "");
    defaultValues.put(Integer.class, 0);
    defaultValues.put(int.class, 0);
    defaultValues.put(Long.class, 0L);
    defaultValues.put(long.class, 0L);
    defaultValues.put(Character.class, '\0');
    defaultValues.put(char.class, '\0');
    // etc
}
```

Fortunately all these types are immutable, so it's okay to return a reference to the same object on each call for the same type.

Comment: @Joonas: Have another look now :)

Comment: I think I'd go for an ?: chain. `type==long.class ? (Long)0L :`, etc.

Comment: @Tom: Any particular reason? Performance? Readability? Once the map is constructed, the method code is basically just the lookup, so that's nice and readable. I'm generally fine with chained conditionals, but in this case I'm not sure I see an advantage. Not much *disadvantage* either, mind you.

Comment: @Jon: how would you want to change your solution if the OP needed to include mutable classes, like StringBuilder?

Comment: @CPerkins: At that point I'd probably change strategy, possibly to something like Tom's suggestion. My answer was aimed at the exact question asked :)

Comment: I guess the rest of the classes (other than primitive) can be created with the newInstance() method as long as they have a nullary constructor. So I just need to check whether the supplied class type is primitive or not, and then return an instance created with Jon's map system or with newInstance().

Comment: Err, except that for instance Integers are not primitive, so I must check against all wrapper classes too!